# How is an authorization server supposed to require client auth for confidential clients?

Tags: oauth

The OAuth2 `password` `grant_type` states,

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described in Section 3.2.1.

Let's assume that I have *both* confidential and non-confidential clients. This seems like a very plausible assumption: I have some third-party developers, who run server side applications, and they are thus issued a `client_id` & `client_secret` pair; I also have a mobile application and a web application; obviously these can't keep the `client_secret` confidential, as they're published publicly.

So, in the case of a public client w/o a client secret, the above "If the client type is confidential" is false, and they don't authenticate with the authorization server as described by §3.2.1.

However, as a server,

> The authorization server MUST:
>
> - require client authentication for confidential clients or for any client that was issued client credentials (or with other authentication requirements),

Okay, but given that the above text means that only confidential clients will send their credentials, how is this possible? If I don't see credentials on the request, **how do I, as an authorization server, know that this is a public client, as opposed to a confidential client that has failed to supply authentication?**

Note that in ["OAuth2 Simplified"](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified), there is an example `grant_type=password` request that includes a `client_id`, but not a `client_secret`; does OAuth *require* that at least a `client_id` is always specified during grants? (And thus, the authorization server *could* identify the client, and thus, whether they need to fully authenticate.) Does the RFC *state* this anywhere?

Comment: Can't you have separate `client_id`'s for confidential and non-confidential clients?

Answer (score 2):

According to [section 2 - client registration](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2) a client is registered with the authorization server before initiating any of the flows.

Client registration includes specifying the client type (confidential or public), and is subsequently assigned a client ID. So when the authorization server receives a request for a given client ID, it knows whether it is confidential or public.

For [authorization code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1) and [implicit](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2.1) grants, the client ID is a required field.

Use of password credentials grant is not recommended, and does not actually require client ID - I mean you're passing your actual credentials directly to the token endpoint, who cares about client ID or client secret!

Comment: Ah, excellent point re the password credentials grant. I was looking primarily at that one (we use it way too much); I did not notice the others specify `client_id` as being required. I'm assuming the implication is that the `client_id` in the body MUST match the `Authorization` header, iff the client passes the secret in via that means? (is this stated anywhere?)

Comment: Yes, passing it via `Authorization` header is recommended, and has to match the corresponding `client_id`. Spec also says you can pass them in the request body https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.3.1 but not recommended.

Comment: My _assumption_ (and yours) is that it must match. I actually don't see where §2.3.1 says that.

While earlier, you had me convinced about password grants, I am now not convinced. I had forgotten that that section *explicitly* requires the client_id.

Comment: `client_id` and `client_secret` must match by inference. Client registration requires you specify `client_type` and if it is confidential, you will need to specify something in order to establish confidentiality such as a `client_secret`; auth server then associates that registration with a unique `client_id` as per §2.2.